# How to create instance from properties That is a Class?

Tags: c#

See my Problem:

```
public class Address
{
public string Title{get;set;}
public string Description{get;set;}
}
public class Tell
{
 public string Title{get;set;}
 public string Number{get;set;}
}
 public class Person
{
 public string FirstName{get;set;}
 public string LastName{get;set;}
 public Address PAddress {get;set;}
 public Tell PTell {get;set;}

 void CreateInstanceFromProperties()
  {
    foreach(var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
     {
       if(prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
          {
            //Create Instance from this property
          }

     }
  }
}
```

I want Create from My Property if its a Class

Comment: Firstly, please use real code - C# is case sensitive; you can't use "Class" and "Public", you mean "foreach" instead of "freeach" etc. Secondly, how do you want to create an instance - just call the parameterless constructor?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I Edit My question...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to call the parameterless constructor, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) very simply. If you want to supply arguments or something more complicated, it gets slightly hairier, but it's still feasible. You haven't said what you want to do with the instance afterwards though:

```
foreach (var prop in this.GetType().GetProperties())
{
     if (prop.PropertyType.IsClass)
     {
         object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(prop.PropertyType);
         // Step 2: ???
         // Step 3: Profit!
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Assembly.CreateInstance method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.createinstance.aspx